Python RDS DB2 connection: TypeError: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is not found
I'm trying to connect to a DB2 instance running in RDS using Python.
I rely on jaydebeapi for that and rely on the doc.
Despite several tries, I still facing the issue in title.
My code is below. Any idea what is missing?
import jaydebeapi

# variable set hidden

def connectStr (dbName,userName,userPassword,dbHostName,dbPort):
    """" Create the DB connection string """
    connStr = []
    credentials = []
    url = 'jdbc:db2://%s:%s/%s:securityMechanism=9;encryptionAlgorithm=2;' % (dbHostName,dbPort,dbName)
    credentials.append (userName)
    credentials.append (userPassword)
    connStr.append ('com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver')
    connStr.append (url)
    connStr.append (credentials)
    
    return connStr

def connectDB (config):
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(config[0],config[1],config[2])
    return conn

connStr = connectStr (dbName,userName,userPassword,dbHostName,dbPort)
conn = connectDB (connStr)

cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """ select count(*) from {} """.format(tableName)
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.close()

I expect the connection to happen and run the query.
I checked the security limitation, and confirm I can manage access from a local DBeaver.

Amazon  RDS for Db2 is also connectable without jaydebeapi, i.e you can also connect with the python ibm_db module (which uses odbc not jdbc).  How did you install the Db2 jdbc driver? Which version you of db2jcc4.jar are you using? Did you test connectivity with raw jdbc before trying jaydebeapi? Does your python process have a valid CLASSPATH environment variable that includes the Db2 jdbc driver? Basic problem determination needed. Seems a configuration matter instead of a programming matter.

It looks like you are missing the jvm in your code. If no CLASSPATH is set, you may want to point to the db2jcc4.jar location. Give a try to the example below:
def connectDB (config):
    jar = './Db2JdbcDriver/db2jcc4.jar' # location of the jdbc driver jar         
    args='-Djava.class.path=%s' % jar
    jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
    jpype.startJVM(jvm, args)
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(config[0],config[1],config[2])
    return conn

